# How do dump the SQL query for debugging purpose of a repository search in Shopware 6?

Tags: php, debugging, shopware

How can I dump the SQL query of something like

```
$searchResult = $this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->search($criteria, $context);
```

I know there is a the debug bar, but this is inside of a PHPUnit test and the debug bar is not available there?

Comment: The debug bar is not available, because it is hardly tied to HTTP foundation - TIL!: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/21141

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2:** This is also included in [FroshDevelopmentHelper](https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshDevelopmentHelper#sql-logger-for-console-debugging)

---

Something like this before the test basically works:

```
Kernel::getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new EchoSQLLogger());
```

This will print out the SQL queries to the console.

Drawbacks:

- Parameters are not inlined into the SQL query
- UUID parameters are displayed as binary data, making it hard to copy&paste them to debug the query

**Improved version - using the Core code to format the query:**

**Warning, not perfect, see comments**

```
class EchoRunableSQLLogger implements \Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger
{
    public function startQuery($sql, ?array $params = null, ?array $types = null)
    {
        $doctrineExtension = new \Shopware\Core\Profiling\Twig\DoctrineExtension();
        echo $doctrineExtension->replaceQueryParameters(
            $sql, 
            array_merge($params ?? array(), $types ?? array())
        ) . ';' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function stopQuery()
    {
    }
}


\Shopware\Core\Kernel::getConnection()->getConfiguration()->setSQLLogger(new EchoRunableSQLLogger());
```

Comment: Damn it  This answer costed me 2 hours :D But thanks for the hint, it was a brilliant start which would be without even worse. What is the problem? `array_merge($params ?? array(), $types ?? array())` overwrites the params with the type, so I thought my query has the wrong parameters - but no, the debug output was wrong  No offense - it was fun to debug. I only thinks this is a fun story about "be careful with assumptions" sometimes the eye is broken, not the reality

Comment: Wow. I think the version in the dev helper does not suffer this problem ? https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshDevelopmentHelper/blob/0.3/src/Doctrine/EchoSQLLogger.php

Answer (score 0):

I have the problem, that @Alex doesn't work for me, because on dev, Shopware is interfering at two positions:

```
src/Kernel.php:49
vendor/shopware/core/HttpKernel.php:179
```

So I just hacked the core:

```
\Shopware\Core\Profiling\Doctrine\DebugStack::startQuery
```

And added the few lines directly into DebugStack:

```
public function startQuery($sql, ?array $params = null, ?array $types = null): void
{
    $this->ensureMasterSlaveCompatibility($sql);

    $doctrineExtension = new \Shopware\Core\Profiling\Twig\DoctrineExtension();
    echo $doctrineExtension->replaceQueryParameters(
            $sql,
            array_merge($params ?? array())
        ) . ';' . PHP_EOL;

    parent::startQuery($sql, $params, $types);
}
```